# Fail to start MySQL server after changing the value of innodb_log_file_size

Tags: mysql

I try to modify the value in my.cnf. However, after I added the innodb configuration in the file, the server is not able to start. I tried to delete the log file and restart the server, but it doesn't work. How to solve it? Thank you. The followings are my script:

```
    #
    # The MySQL database server configuration file.
    #
    # You can copy this to one of:
    # - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
    # - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
    #
    # One can use all long options that the program supports.
    # Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
    # --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
    #
    # For explanations see
    # http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

    # This will be passed to all mysql clients
    # It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
    # escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
    # Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
    [client]
    port     = 3306
    socket       = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

    # Here is entries for some specific programs
    # The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

    # This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
    [mysqld_safe]
    socket       = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    nice     = 0

    [mysqld]
    #
    # * Basic Settings
    #
    user     = mysql
    pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
    socket       = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    port     = 3306
    basedir      = /usr
    datadir      = /var/lib/mysql
    tmpdir       = /tmp
    lc-messages-dir    = /usr/share/mysql
    skip-external-locking
    #
    # Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
    # localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
    bind-address     = 127.0.0.1
    #
    # * Fine Tuning
    #
    key_buffer       = 32M
    max_allowed_packet    = 32M
    thread_stack     = 256K
    thread_cache_size       = 8
    sort_buffer_size = 8M
    read_buffer_size = 2M
    read_rnd_buffer_size = 16M
    myisam-recover      = BACKUP
    table_cache         = 500
    thread_concurrency  = 8
    #
    # * Query Cache Configuration
    #
    query_cache_limit    = 1M
    query_cache_size        = 32M
    #
    # * Logging and Replication
    #
    # Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
    # Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
    # As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
    #general_log_file       = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
    #general_log            = 1
    #
    # Error log - should be very few entries.
    #
    log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
    #
    # Here you can see queries with especially long duration
    #log_slow_queries    = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
    #long_query_time = 2
    #log-queries-not-using-indexes
    #
    # The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
    # note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
    #       other settings you may need to change.
    #server-id       = 1
    #log_bin         = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
    expire_logs_days    = 10
    max_binlog_size         = 100M
    #binlog_do_db        = include_database_name
    #binlog_ignore_db    = include_database_name
    #
    # * InnoDB
    #
    # InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
    # Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
    #
    # * Security Features
    #
    # Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
    # chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
    #
    # For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
    #
    # ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
    # ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
    # ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem

    #innodb configuration
    innodb_data_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql/
    innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:200M:autoextend
    innodb_log_group_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql/
    innodb_log_arch_dir = /var/lib/mysql/
    innodb_buffer_pool_size = 5G 
    innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M
    innodb_log_file_size = 256M
    innodb_log_files_in_group = 4
    innodb_log_buffer_size = 4M
    innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
    innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 60
    innodb_support_xa = 0
    innodb_thread_concurrency = 8
    innodb_file_per_table

    sync-binlog = 1

    [mysqldump]
    quick
    quote-names
    max_allowed_packet    = 16M

    [mysql]
    #no-auto-rehash    # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

    [isamchk]
    key_buffer       = 16M

    #
    # * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
    #   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
    #
    !includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: Is the problem similar to this? http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/07/09/how-to-change-innodb_log_file_size-safely/ ?

Comment: Yes, they are similar. MySQL provides the document to explain how to change the innodb configuration safely and I follow them. However, it still does not work.